# Any chance to make increment of Brownian motion bounded?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the increment of Brownian motion. It is of infinite variation, so the sum
$$\sum_i^{n-1} | B(t_{i+1})- B(t_i) |$$ for all possible partitions of the time interval $[0,T]$ is not bounded.
Now, consider that we add a variable $a_t >0$, such that we have
$$\sum_i^{n-1} a_t | B(t_{i+1})- B(t_i) |$$
where $\sum_i a_{t_i}^2 < \infty$ but $\sum_i a_{t_i} = \infty$.

Which conditions should the variable $a$ satisfy to make this sum of increments bounded?

Comment: The most obvious choice is $a_{t_i}=| B(t_{i+1})- B(t_i) |\,.$ It might help to provide some context.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, if you allow for random choices, then you can just take $a_{t_{i},t_{i+1}}=| B(t_{i+1})- B(t_i) |$.

If you want deterministic choice, then you can use the modulus results for BM from the Peres-Morters book on Brownian motion lemma 1.16
[image]

So on top of the constraints you mentioned we also require

$$ \sum  a_{t_{i},t_{i+1}}\sqrt{(t_{i+1}-t_{i})\log\frac{1}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}}<\infty$$

so that

$$\sum  a_{t_{i},t_{i+1}}| B(t_{i+1})- B(t_i) |<\infty.$$

Comment: Is this also valid if we do not consider the absolute value of the increments?

Comment: @Ankakusu what do you mean by "this"? The lemma's upper bound is still true since $|f|\geq f$.

Comment: Is the sum of increments of Brownian motion bounded if we do not take the absolute value? Do we have $\sum_{i=0}^n B(i+1)- B(i) = B_n - B_0$?

Comment: @Ankakusu yes that is true for every function.